# C#, Api ошибка Unauthorized 401

Tags: c#, api, http, restsharp

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой, пишу автотесты для Api, но получаю **Unauthorized**
Вот код:

```
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("url");
        request.AddHeader("Ip", "10.1.1.1");
        request.AddHeader("UserName", "USER");
        request.AddHeader("HttpSessionId", "111111111");
        request.AddHeader("SourceService", "APP");
        request.AddHeader("SessionId", DataKey);
        request.AddHeader("X-Gateway-Api-Key", "key");
        request.AddJsonBody(json);
        var res = client.Execute(request);
```

Client соответственно объявлен выше RestClient
Дело в том, что в Postman, если я поле:

> ("X-Gateway-Api-Key", "key");

передаю в раздел авторизации, а не в заголовки, то все работает, но если данное поле идет в сам раздел Headers, получаю ошибку авторизации, помогите, пожалуйста, провести анологию с постман.

Comment: Почему не используете `HttpClient`?

Comment: Фрейм, с которым работаю использует библиотеку RestSharp, можно конечно и им попробовать, но в моем понимании это вроде как аналогичные инструменты, или я ошибаюсь

Comment: У меня просто подозрение, что он мой ключ по пути теряет, хотя в запросе он имеется, в чем дело понять не могу, либо стоит попробовать использовать AddParameter

Comment: На уровне HTTP это работает так - [документация](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.1). Почему HttpClient = потому что он умеет авторизацию сам делать, там есть специализированный заголовок `HttpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization`. А здесь кажется вам надо руками сгенерировать значение заголовка. Предполагаю, что тип авторизации `Bearer`.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за наводку, буду пробовать

Comment: Весь смысл решения исходит из ошибки 401, по спецификации HTTP это означает, что сервер ожидает от вас заголовок `Authorization`.